# What is special about programs that create bootable USB sticks for Linux?

Tags: system-installation, bootable

Why couldn't I just mount the ISO and copy the files over to the stick?

Comment: Every OS needs a bootloader to work, at least on x86

Answer (score 2):

The ISO filesystem is read-only, and those bootable Linux images are usually created in a way where they are *both* a bootable ISO and a bootable hard-disk image (with bootrecord and partition table), so they could be copied to either a CD or a USB stick.

You can however create your own modifiable and bootable USB stick if you don't intend to ever burn it to a CD or DVD: partition it with fdisk(1), install grub(1) on it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is special about the programs, but they do create a special program on the USB storage: they create a program called a boot loader.